# difference between ng-class ternary operator and evaluating an expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have expression 
`ng-class="myVal > 0 ? 'myClass' : 'none'"`, where `myVal` gets value after some ajax request in controller.

The problem is, sometimes `myVal` gets new value in controller but the above class does not updated in the view.

However, expression like `ng-class="{'myClass' : myVal > 0}"` giving correct result everytime.

What is the difference between the two? or should i use `ngClass` in different way?

Comment: They are different. The first one switches between `myClass` and `none`. The last toggles `myClass`. Equivalent version should be `ng-class="{'myClass' : myVal > 0, 'none': myVal <= 0}"`. BTW both options should work [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SDSQAAL6ZkgIhyqw2Zbp?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

The `ngClass` directive accept an expression as string, object and array. [Check the documentation about ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Controller:

```
// string
$scope.myClassString = 'my-style';

// object
$scope.myClassObject = {
    'my-style-a': true, // true expression 
    'my-style-b': 2 > 1, // true expression 
    'my-style-c': false // false expression style not applied
};

// array with mixed values
$scope.myClassArray = [
    'my-style-d',
    {
        'my-style-e': true, // true expression 
        'my-style-f': false // false expression style not applied
    }
];
```

View:

```
<div ng-class="myClassString"> 

</div>

<div ng-class="myClassObject"> 

</div>

<div ng-class="myClassArray"> 

</div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-class="'my-style'""> 

</div>

<div ng-class="{'my-style-a': true, 'my-style-b': 2 > 1, 'my-style-c': false}"> 

</div>

<div ng-class="['my-style-d', {'my-style-e': true, 'my-style-f': false }]"> 

</div>
```